# Make new column from two columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have two columns sales(in crs) and sales_price and I want to make a new column no_of_unit_Sold from these columns (no_of_unit_sold = sales * 10000000 / sales_price)
How can I do it in power BI

Answer (score 0):

first it is good that you know the differences between both components. Which is a calculated measure and a column, for this I leave you the following link where you can review. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/

When you select the dataset, you can go to the modeling section
[image]

For example, for a measure:

```
TableName[no_of_unit_sold] := DIVIDE(SUM(sales) * 10000000, sales_price)
```

If you want to make it as a column:

```
TableName[no_of_unit_sold] = sales * 10000000 / sales_price
```

I hope it serves as a guide, greetings